# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)

Tags: php

I tried to translate the "new" label in Magento 2 but now it show Http error 500. For example, I changed `<span>new</span>` to `<span data-bind="i18n: 'new'"></span>` in the code below. What did I do wrong?

```
function newLabel($_product) {
  $output='';
  $now = date("Y-m-d");
  $newsFrom = substr($_product->getNewsFromDate(), 0, 10);
  $newsTo = substr($_product->getNewsToDate(), 0, 10);
  $new = false;

  if (!empty($newsFrom) && !empty($newsTo)) {
    if ($now >= $newsFrom && $now <= $newsTo) $new = true;
  } elseif (!empty($newsFrom) && empty($newsTo)) {
    if ($now >= $newsFrom) $new = true;
  } elseif (empty($newsFrom) && !empty($newsTo)) {
    if ($now <= $newsTo) $new = true;
  }
  // I'm trying to change this line:
  if ($new) $output='<div class="product_holder__label product_holder__label--right product_holder__label--new"> <span>new</span> </div>';
  return $output; 
}
```

In the `error_log`, I can see this if I try the translation:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /home/.../.../app/code/vendor/module/Helper/Data.php
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: Can't replicate.  There are no syntax errors in the given code.

Comment: If you change to `<span data-bind="i18n: 'new'"></span>` you have the quotes messed up. `'` in this case.

Comment: It is line: if ($new)$output='<div class="product_holder__label product_holder__label--right product_holder__label--new"> <span data-bind="i18n: 'new'"></span></div>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not paying attention to proper quoting. As far as I can tell, you are replacing this line:

```
if ($new)$output='... <span>new</span> ...';
```

Directly with this:

```
if ($new)$output='... <span data-bind="i18n: 'new'"></span> ...';
```

This is a problem because the single quotes around `new` get misinterpreted as the end of the string `'... <span data-bind="i18n: '` and the other as the beginning of the string `'"></span> ...'`.

You need to escape the single quotes with a backslash:

```
if ($new)$output='... <span data-bind="i18n: \'new\'"></span> ...';
```

Comment: I need edit my comment... This doesn't work for translate magento 2. 1. I tried put translate .csv file text: new,second language. 2. I tried use also translate inline tool but after ssh command upgrade and compile, translated text is lost. Anything idea how i can get it works?

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the OP.

But
I was redirected here, for the same error search.

My case:
The project was working on server1.
For R&D i uploaded this same code on server2.
On server2 i faced the above error.

**Reason:**
**"Support for 'NEW' was added in PHP 7.0"**

So i checked my PHP version and it was lower.
Check you PHP version with phpinfo();